# Can Clementine's media control be integrated into the GNOME panel?

Tags: gnome-shell, music, clementine

I don't know if I missed some settings or is this commonly known issue with Clementine...

I've tried different music players, and Clementine seems like the best fit. The only thing I'm missing is integration with the GNOME panel on my Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried Amarok, RhytmBox, Audacity and every one of these has the possibility to pause/play and skip to previous/next song when you click on a clock on the top bar, like in this image:

[image: gnome panel media control]

But I'm missing this feature in Clementine. The only way to do this is from Ubuntu dock, which I'm not used to.

Can this be somehow set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[Media Player Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/55/media-player-indicator/)** GNOME shell extension. It let's you control MPRIS version 2 capable media players. It supports Clementine.

[image]

Refer to this for installing and managing GNOME extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481)